# C++ VS15 linking problems with windows.security.cryptography.h

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Hello I'm quite a noob with linking in windows and linux (I'm a C# programmer)

I have included:

```
#include <windows.security.cryptography.h>
```

because I want to use RSA sign.
but when I compile I get a linking error:

ERROR LNK 2019: reference to the external symbol __imp__CryptDecodeObjectEx@32 not resolved...

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and I hope to not get errors on Linux :)

Comment: Most likely you are not linking to the library file.

Comment: Building C++ applications is a three-step process: 1) Edit code; 2) Compile code; 3) *Link* code. The error is coming from the third step, where you don't link with the actual library. Including header files is happening at step 2, and header files only contains information needed to create the files used by step 3.